# Where should I place the application logic for login functionality?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication, datamapper, service-layer

I have a question regarding the best place to store fairly complicated application logic.

Say I want to allow a user to log into the site. The process of logging in should entail the following steps:

1. From the form field, hash the user's email
2. Look up the user's email hash in the auth table to make sure a user
   exists (auth table stores only encrypted email, email hash, user_id,
   and password hash)
3. If user is found, then validate their password
4. Regenerate the session id
5. Store the new session in the database

Using the data mapper pattern, I have the following three models which are involved in this process

```
/User/
 - User.php
 - UserMapper.php

/Auth/
 - Auth.php
 - AuthMapper.php

/Session/
 - Session.php
 - SessionMapper.php
```

Thus a function which logs the user in would look something like this:

```
function login($email, $password)
{
    $security = new \Lib\Security;
    $authMapper = new \Models\Auth\AuthMapper($this->db);
    $userMapper = new \Models\User\UserMapper($this->db);
    $session = new \Models\Session\Session;
    $sessionMapper = new \Models\Session\SessionMapper($this->db);

    $email_hash = $security->simpleHash($email);

    if (!$auth = $authMapper->fetchWhere('email_hash', $email_hash))
    {
        echo 'User doesnt exist'; 
        return;
    }

    if (!$auth->verifyPassword($password))
    {
        echo 'Password not correct'; 
        return;
    }

    $user = $userMapper->fetchById($auth->user_id);

    $session->createUserSession($user);

    $sessionMapper->save($session);
}
```

There are a few concerns here. First is the lack of dependency injection. The second is that this a cumbersome chunk of code to use every place I might want to provide login functionality.

So where should this logic live? In a controller? In the User domain object? In the Auth domain object? That seems kind of circular - the whole point of the data mapper is so that the domain object doesn't deal with persistence of even itself, let alone OTHER objects.... Should it be placed in a User or Auth service layer within either the /User/ or /Auth/ models?

I'm a bit lost as to the best practice for this sort of thing.

Also keep in mind I'm going this for learning purposes, so I don't want to just use something like Symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I've decided that the best place for this is to create an `AccountController` that accepts a `LoginHandlerInterface` interface as a constructor argument.

The AccountController then looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class AccountController
{
    protected $LoginHandler;

    public function __construct(\Framework\Interfaces\LoginHandlerInterface $LoginHandler)
    {
        $this->LoginHandler = $LoginHandler;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if (/* ...  form validation stuff ... */)
        {
            try 
            {
                $this->LoginHandler->login($email, $password);
            }
            catch (\Framework\Exceptions\Login $e) 
            {
                // Assign login errors to template etc...
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Then whichever `LoginHandler` I end up using, has everything it needs to do all of the logging in (looking up the user, validating the password, updating the session etc). This keeps my `AccountController` clean, flexible, and testable.

I inject the desired `LoginHandler` (and `RegistrationHandler`, which I haven't shown here) via a configuration in an IoC container that auto-resolves constructor dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Auth should handle the login if it fails returns false,
 if it's true do the session's logic and returns true.

So in your controller you will do something like if(Auth->login($email,$password))

ps: For this type of workflow, i prefer to use Singleton pattern ( tho it ruins Unit Testing ), but i do think it will suit you better.